# Simple Jquery slide not working?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a simple FlexSlider 2 slideshow on my website however it isn't working the images just go on to the page underneath each other? I'm new to Jquery so just stuck as to why it won't work?
I have these links in my header.php

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
```

slideshow.php

```
<script src="assets/js/slideshow.js"></script> //js and images are in assets folder
<div class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">
        <li>
            <img src="assets/images/winter.jpg" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="assets/images/sunset.jpg" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="assets/images/dock.jpg" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="assets/images/snow.jpg" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="custom-navigation">
    <a href="#" class="flex-prev">Prev</a>
    <div class="custom-controls-container"></div>
    <a href="#" class="flex-next">Next</a>
</div>
```

slideshow.js

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('.flexslider').flexslider({
            animation: "slide",
            controlsContainer: $(".custom-controls-container"),
            customDirectionNav: $(".custom-navigation a")
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: First of all, do not load jQuery 3 times.

Comment: Can you check if you have error on JS console ?

Comment: on my webpage it says that jquery was not found but it is linked to my header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Remove the second script and the fourth one.
2. Be sure that Jquery fires before FlexSlider.

**Example:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div class="flexslider">
<ul class="slides">
<li>
  <img src="assets/images/winter.jpg" />
</li>
<li>
  <img src="assets/images/sunset.jpg" />
</li>
<li>
  <img src="assets/images/dock.jpg" />
</li>
<li>
  <img src="assets/images/snow.jpg" />
</li>
</ul>
</div>
  <div class="custom-navigation">
 <a href="#" class="flex-prev">Prev</a>
 <div class="custom-controls-container"></div>
 <a href="#" class="flex-next">Next</a>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
     $(window).load(function() {
     $('.flexslider').flexslider({
     animation: "slide",
     controlsContainer: $(".custom-controls-container"),
     customDirectionNav: $(".custom-navigation a")
     });
     });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

///// Replace your slideshow.js code by this ////

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $('.flexslider').flexslider({
 animation: "slide",
 controlsContainer: $(".custom-controls-container"),
 customDirectionNav: $(".custom-navigation a")
 });
 });
```